# Why is this Parsing Expression Grammar left recursive?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I'm trying to get my parser generator to accept this specification. I know that's kind of a programming question, but I figured this was the best place to ask. It's specified as a Parsing Expression Grammar, I think.

```
start   = Expr

Expr    = [0-9]+ / Sum / Product / '(' Expr ')'
Product = Expr '*' Expr
Sum     = Expr '+' Expr
```

Note: I know nothing about formal grammars beyond what I've read on Wikipedia. If there are any good online resources, I'd love to hear about it.

In any case, my generator is throwing this error:

```
Left recursion detected for rule "Expr".
```

What I find strange is that it's perfectly willing to accept this:

```
start   = Expr

Expr    = [0-9]+ / '(' Expr ')'
```

Which looks just as recursive as the first one to me.

Comment: The symbol `/` is normally written as `|` and means an alternative. Specifically `Expr = '(' Expr ')'` is recursive, but it not left recursive since the left-most symbol is a terminal symbol, i.e. '('. However, `Product` introduces indirectly a rule `Expr = Expr '*' Expr` where the left-most right-hand-side symbol is the same as left side non-terminal, and this introduces left recursion. Besides, http://cs.stackexchange.com or http://stackoverflow.com are much better to ask this kind of question, and there is a lot on the net about this topic, but [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=left+recursion).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A "left-recursive" grammar means that the parser can get into a loop in the parsing rules without making any progress consuming the input.  Imagine that each production is a subroutine that might eat some tokens or call some other subroutines.  For example, consider this production:

```
expr → number '+' number
```

This means that the `expr` parser will first call the `number` parser (which might consume some tokens), then try to eat a `+` token (and fail if the next token is not of that type) and then call the `number` parser again to consume more tokens.  If that is all successful, the `expr` parser will yield success.

Now consider this left-recursive production:

```
expr → expr '+' expr
```

The first thing the `expr` parser will do is to call itself recursively, putting itself into an unproductive infinite loop.

In contrast, consider this production, which is *not* left-recursive:

```
expr → '(' expr ')'
```

The first thing the parser will do is try to consume an open parenthesis token, and it will call itself recursively only if that is successful.  It can never get into an infinite loop doing this because there are only so many parentheses and it has to eat one each time before it can recurse; eventually it must run out of parentheses and then the recursion will stop. Your `Expr    = [0-9]+ / '(' Expr ')'` example is similarly safe.

Here is a portion of the left-recursive grammar you showed:

```
expr → [0-9]+ | sum
sum  → expr '*' expr
```

If the next token is *not* `[0-9]+`, then the `expr` parser will call `sum`, which will immediately call `expr` again, and the parser will be in an infinite loop.

Usually you can rewrite rules like `sum` in a non-left-recursive form.  In this case it will look something like this:

```
expr       → term more_terms
more_terms → '*' term more_terms | '+' term more_terms | <nothing>
term       → [0-9]+ | '(' expr ')'
```

This is not left-recursive because the `more_terms` parser must consume a `*` or a `+` token before it can call itself recursively; it is impossible for the parser to get into an infinite loop by doing this. Similarly the `expr` parser calls `term`, but `term` will not call back to `expr` without consuming a parenthesis.

In general the transformation says to turn a left-recursive grammar like this:

```
S → S 'p' | 'q'
```

into a non-left-recursive one like this:

```
S  → 'q' ps 
ps → 'p' ps | <nothing>
```

I don't know if there are any *good* online resources (I suppose there must be) but if you like Perl, [chapter 8 of *Higher-Order Perl*](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/08Parsing.pdf) is available online and discusses precisely this point.

Also, I hope it is not insulting to suggest that you read [the Wikipedia article about left recursion](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Left_recursion), and perhaps [the article about recursive descent parsing](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Recursive_descent), which is the name for the technique your parser generator is trying to use.

Comment: In your transformation `ps` should be on the right side of `'q'`, e.g. originally it was `S = qp*`, but after the change it is `S = p*q`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I really understand yet but I'm at least a bit closer.

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks.

Comment: I originally needed the answer to this question because I need to build a parser for a small string-processing language that I've invented (which I need for a pet-project), but now I've actually become interested in the field of Formal Grammar as a whole. If there are no good, comprehensive online resources, can you suggest a textbook?

Comment: @JackM I recommend *Parsing Techniques: A Practical Guide* by Dick Grune and Ceriel Jacobs.  [It is available for free download](http://dickgrune.com/Books/PTAPG_1st_Edition/).

Comment: After struggling with the concept and wikipedia article for some time, your expr/term example somehow finally made the concept click. +1